# Activate window in NodObjC

Tags: objective-c, node.js, cocoa, nodobjc

I'm stuck on trying to activate a window in OSX from node using nodobjc.

Here's what I have:

```
var $ = require('nodobjc');
$.framework('Cocoa');

//found window is returned from CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo left out for brevity's sake
const app = $.NSRunningApplication('runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier',foundWindow.kCGWindowOwnerPID);

app('activateWithOptions', 'NSApplicationActivateAllWindows');
```

app is holding a pointer to the correct process id and app name if I console.log(app) I see something like:

`<NSRunningApplication: 0x103f14540 (com.apple.calculator - 9274)>`

Now according to other questions around the place in obj-c you would get an app object back and call activateWithOptions and NSApplicationActivateAllWindows being the option. Apple docs here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication.activationoptions

When I run this, however nothing happens. I can basically send in what I want instead of NSApplicationActivateAllWindows and nothing happens. I've tried the other options available, same thing.

How can I get the application to activate and come to the foreground?

Comment: Did you try no options `0`?

Comment: I got so frustrated with this I tried passing in random strings and then numbers. It turns out passing in the number 27 works! Definitely not the answer so I'll leave it open but it seems to consistently work. I am guessing the options are integers but there's no mapping of their values online so I have no idea what 27 means